# How to determine if an element is displayed on screen for specific time using selenium java/python?

Tags: java, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

There is an webelement(Success or failure message) which gets displayed on screen only for 3 seconds. How can I assure that the element is displayed on screen for 3 seconds using selenium java OR python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.time.LocalDateTime` and `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` combine with `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions`.

In this example the time a button is not enabled is measured:

```
package selenium;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DeviTimeTest {

    public static String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    public static String chromedriverPath = userDir + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";  
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/dynamic-properties");
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("enableAfter"));
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button));
        LocalDateTime finish = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("Button was disabled for " + ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(start, finish) + " ms.");
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 47769
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Pro 06, 2021 8:00:55 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Button was disabled for 4404 ms.
```